# How to regex a version number in python?

Tags: python, regex

In python 3.6 I want to match a version number, i.e. a string that contains numbers and dots.

Here is what I have tried:

```
re.search(r"([\d\.+]+)", str)
```

but this also matches `str="2020"` which obviously does not contain a dot. Although I require at least one dot to match! Is that a bug or what am I misunderstanding from the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax) about the `+` sign?

I also tried

```
re.search(r"(\d+\.+)", "2020.4.3")
```

which does match, but only returns the string "2020.".

Here are some test cases:

```
abba -> No match
2020 -> No match
1.1.1.1 -> 1.1.1.1
2020.4.3 -> 2020.4.3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regex in python to ensure at least one dot:

```
r'\b\d+(?:\.\d+)+'
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/uSrfdG/1)

**RegEx Details:**

- `\b`: Word boundary
- `\d+`: Match 1+ digits
- `(?:\.\d+)+`: Match a group 1+ times containing dot followed by 1+ digits

Comment: Does not work for me. When I use `2020.2` as a test string it returns nothing

Comment: That's not correct, it will return full match. Are you using `findall`?

Comment: @Alex You must've done something wrong. Double-check the pattern. Side note:  you might want to replace the last `+` with `{1,3}` (or `{0,3}` if you want to also match numbers only without dots).

Comment: I am using `search`, see question

Comment: Yes, I did copy it incorrectly. It seems to work, thanks a lot

Comment: Indeed `re.search(r'\b\d+(?:\.\d+)+', "2020.2").group(0)` will return `2020.2`

Comment: What does the `?:` do?

Comment: `(?:..)` is a non-capturing group so that we don't make unnecessary groups.

Comment: Can you repeat that in english please?

Comment: @Alex See: [What is a non-capturing group in regular expressions?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3512471/8967612)

Comment: Yes, found it in the docs...

Comment: But still unclear to me'

Comment: [Rede about non-capturing groups](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html#:~:text=Non%2DCapturing%20Groups&text=The%20question%20mark%20and%20the,the%20end%20of%20the%20regex.&text=This%20regex%20has%20no%20quantifiers.)

Comment: Sometimes documentation can be more confusing than explanative. As I understand it is used to find a match, but is not 'returned' as a result. No still unclear to me related to my question. So basically I could  remove it, then the whole expression is used as a match. Yes ehat I want! But then it is not working anymore

Comment: It is working because of `+` after group which makes sure 1 or more occurrence of `.` and digits

Comment: Thanks, that is an expression I can understand now